# Force Flutter not lose data when changing pages in the BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, state

My `flutter` app has a `bottomNavigationBar` widget and it actually works fine and so...

The problem is I lose the data from the `API` call after I change the page to another page and then when I get back I have to `re-fetch` everything again!

What is the best way to avoid this?

The code

```dart
// ...Some code...

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<wp.Post> posts = [];
  int _pageNumber = 1;

  Future<String> getPosts() async {
    var res = await fetchPosts(_pageNumber);
    setState(() {
      posts = res;
    });
    return "Success!";
  }

  // Get posts when app loads;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      this.getPosts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return buildPost(context, posts, index); //Building the posts list view
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: save the api response to a variable so that you can reuse

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin" to keep the state of your pages.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin { //<== add mixin
  List<wp.Post> posts = [];
  int _pageNumber = 1;

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true; //<== add this line 

  Future<String> getPosts() async {
    var res = await fetchPosts(_pageNumber);
    setState(() {
      posts = res;
    });
    return "Success!";
  }

  // Get posts when app loads;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      this.getPosts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    super.build(context); // <== add this line
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return buildPost(context, posts, index); //Building the posts list view
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I add this to all my pages that I want their states to stay? Or, just in one page? I noticed that after just implementing it in one page all other pages that depend on this same response keep their state too!

Comment: Yes, only add the mixin to pages where you want the states to stay alive.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use IndexedStack. for Example:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final List<Widget> myTabs = [
    Tab(text: 'one'),
    Tab(text: 'two'),
    Tab(text: 'three'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;
  int _tabIndex = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  _handleTabSelection() {
    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      setState(() {
        _tabIndex = _tabController.index;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _tabs = [
      One(),
      Two(),
      Three(),
    ];

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
    controller: _tabController,
    labelColor: Colors.redAccent,
    tabs: myTabs,
  ),
  body: IndexedStack(
    children: _tabs,
    index: _tabIndex,
  ),
);
  }
}
```

for more information of IndexedStack visit [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html)